# flutter crash: Codec failed to produce an image, possibly due to invalid image data

Tags: flutter

My Flutter app crashed and the reason for the crash was "Codec failed to produce an image, possibly due to invalid image data." Upon investigating the relevant code in Flutter, I found that the error occurred in the getNextFrame() method in the painting.dart file when the image was null.

The images displayed in my app are first sent to me as a base64 string from the backend. I then convert the image to a Uint8List format using convert.Base64Decoder().convert(imageBase64) and save it locally using the File's writeAsBytes method. At the same time, I use the image library's decodeImage method to obtain the width and height of the image, which is also saved locally. All the images displayed in the app are local images, accessed using the File(imagePath) method. I don't understand why the "Codec failed to produce an image" error is still occurring.

At first, I thought the crash was caused by the decodeImageFromList method. So I changed the method of obtaining the image width and height to use the decodeImage method from the image library. However, this did not solve the issue, and the crash still occurred.